# IMG in vuepress is not showing

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I try to learn Vuepress and I need to know how to add image to document.

I tried code from documentation on vuepress `![An image](images/image.png)` and can't see nothing

[image: Tree]

Code I tried to use in **frontend.md** and is really simple

```
# Title

![An image](images/image.jpg)
```

Here is result of that code

[image: result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommended that you [reference any asset using relative URLs](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/assets.html#relative-urls). You can move your images into the content folder:

```
content
  frontend.md
  assets
    images
      image.jpg
```

Then reference using relative URL in `frontend.md`:

```
![An image](./assets/images/image.jpg)
```